# Tableview cell change cell backgroung image(png) on click

Tags: iphone

I want to highlit cell when user click on the cell in the function didselectrowatindexpath.?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- modify the cell directly in your `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method (but I've had some visual glitch issues with this technique, [Problem modifying UITableViewCell accessoryType in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022490/problem-modifying-uitableviewcell-accessorytype-in-tableviewdidselectrowatindexp)):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // do stuff with cell
    //
}
```

- set appropriate state in your data model, and call `[tableView reloadData]`, which in turn will result in a call to `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, where you set up the cell to display according to your data model.